# Making a 2D dict readable

Tags: python, hash-map

I am building a 2d dictionary with an altered list at the end Afterwords I want to find the min of each list. Is there a better way to do it? Better being faster or at least less of an eyesore.

```
#dummy function, will be replaced later so don't worry about it.
def alter(x, y, z,):
    a = list(x)
    for i, val in enumerate(x):
         a[i] = val + y + z
    return a

masterStats = {}
askStats = [0, 1, 2]
for numberServed in range(3):
    masterStats[numberServed] = {}
    for timeToServe in range(3):
        masterStats[numberServed][timeToServe] = alter(askStats, numberServed, timeToServe)

for numberServed in masterStats.keys():
    for timeToServe in masterStats[numberServed].keys():
        print(min(masterStats[numberServed][timeToServe]))


for numberServed in masterStats.keys():
    print(numberServed)
    for timeToServe in masterStats[numberServed].keys():
        print("    " + str(timeToServe))
        print("        " + str(masterStats[numberServed][timeToServe]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's variable names are conventionally named lowercase_width_underscores.

Loop using .items() not .keys() if you will need the values, so your final loop can be:

```
for numberServed, numberServedStats in masterStats.items():
    print(numberServed)
    for timeToServe, timeToServeStats in numberServedStats,items():
        print("    " + str(timeToServe))
        print("        " + str(timeToServeStats))
```

The whole thing can be made more efficient by using numpy:

```
askStats = numpy.array([0, 1, 2])

x = askStats[None,None,:] # put askStats in the third dimension
y = numpy.arange(3)[:, None, None] # put number served in the first dimension
z = numpy.arange(3)[None, :, None] # put time to serve in the second dimension

stats = x + y + z # same as in alter
```

We create a new array by adding together three existing arrays. The `[:,None, None]` parts control how they are added. Essentially, the colon indicates the column the data will be spread across. The None indicates where the data will be duplicated. So `numpy.arange(3)[:,None]` gets treated like

```
[ 
    [0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1],
    [2, 2, 2]
]
```

Whereas `numpy.arange(3)[None, :]` gets treated like

```
[
    [0, 1, 2],
    [0, 1, 2],
    [0, 1, 2]
]
```

This lets us do the complete loop and adjust function in just that one expression.

```
for line in stats.min(axis=2).flatten():
    print(line)
```

The min method reduces the 3 dimensional array to 2d array by minimizing along dimension 2. Flatten() converts that 2d array into one long one dimensional array.

```
for row_index, row in enumerate(stats):
    print(row_index)
    for col_index, col in enumerate(row):
        print("    ", col_index)
        print("        ", col)
```

It probably won't help much here, but for bigger cases using numpy will be more efficient.

Comment: You lost me on that second part, can you explain a bit of what you're doing with numpy and flatten?

Comment: @EasilyBaffled, I've added some explanation.

Comment: So to alter it to accept larger data sets, I replace 3 with x in numpy.arange(x) but how do I alter the [None,:,None] to take any amount?

Comment: And how is the alter function run in it?

Comment: @EasilyBaffled, edited to hopefully clarify things a bit.

Comment: @EasilyBaffled, alter function isn't run, its logic is replaced, (edit should make this a bit clearer)

Comment: @EasilyBaffled, you don't need to change the `[None,:,None]`, that just means to put the array into the second dimension. As long as you still want to do that you don't need to change it.

Comment: The edits are helping a lot thanks, but just one more question where in this, would I put the alter function?

Comment: @EasilyBaffled, the get the full advantage, you need to rewrite the alter function to use numpy. The `stats = x + y + z` does the same thing your alter function does, but faster. Your real function is more complicated I guess, but without knowing more I can't really provide much hints as to how.

Comment: The function I'm using runs x*y times and uses all of the variables from list z along with a lot of randomization to produce a new number so sorta like for i in range(x*y): z[i] = (askStats[0] + randomInt(askStats[1], askStats[2]))

Comment: See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html, for the random functions that numpy supports. I'm not sure what range your example is suppose to produce but I think you'll find one of the options there to be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`alter` is equivalent to a list comprehension:

```
def alter(x, y, z):
    return [val + y + z for val in x]
```

`collections.defaultdict(dict)` is a convenient 2-level dictionary. You could also make use of `itertools.product` for 2D looping:

```
masterStats = collections.defaultdict(dict)
askStats = [0, 1, 2]
for numberServed, timeToServe in itertools.product(range(3), range(3)):
    masterStats[numberServed][timeToServe] = alter(askStats, numberServed, timeToServe)
```

Iterate over `values()`:

```
for subdict in masterStats.values():
    for lst in subdict.values():
        print(min(lst))
```

Iterate over `items()`, like Winston already mentioned:

```
for numberServed, subdict in masterStats.items():
    print(numberServed)
    for timeToServe, lst in subdict.items():
        print("    " + str(timeToServe))
        print("        " + str(lst))
```